# How do I manipulate string in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, django

How can I change "2020, 12, 14, 2" to "'2020','12','14','2'" on index.html ?

[image]

Thank you for your time,

Comment: I'm confused. `new Date('2020', '12', '14', '2')` and `new Date(2020, 12, 14, 2)` should return the same value. Can you clarify how the date string currently looks and what you want it to look like?

Comment: Thank you for asking, I've edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method will split up the string into an array of substrings. You can then reference those substrings.

Something like:

```js
let dateStr = "2020,12,14,2";
let subStrs = dateStr.split(",");
// note the use of the spread operator below
console.log(...subStrs);
// convert to a JS date
let date = new Date(...subStrs);
console.log(date);
```

So, as a one-liner:

```js
let dateStr = "2020,12,14,2";
// one-liner below
let date = new Date(...dateStr.split(","));
console.log(date);
```

Note that you may need to subtract 1 from the month value since JS is zero-based (months start at 0).

If you need to format more, you can use the `getMonth()`, `getDate()`, `getYear()`, and/or `toLocaleDatetring()` methods on the `Date` object.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I Didn't understood your question but in JavaScript you can do

```
let input = "Dec. 14. 2020. 2 p.m."
let months = ["Jan" , "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", " May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", " Nov", "Dec"]

let d = input.replace(/\./g, "").split(" ")

let output = d[2] + ", " + (months.indexOf(d[0]) + 1) + ", " + d[1] + ", " + d[3]

console.log(output)
//2020, 12, 14, 2
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I've edited my question to make it clear

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ dateTime | date:"Y,m,d,H" }}
```

It looks like **Liquid** (a server side template language (other examples of those are: smarty, twig). You should look up for a Liquid interpreter and use it.

> **Liquid** is an open-source template language created by Shopify and
> written in Ruby. It is the backbone of Shopify themes and is used to
> load dynamic content on storefronts. - https://shopify.github.io/liquid/

They even show a very similar example with date operartor:
https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/date/

```
{{ article.published_at | date: "%a, %b %d, %y" }}
```

You should use it at the backend and render correct html (without template tags).